# git stash: avoid "on <branch-name>" string in message

Tags: git

with `git stash [save]` command, it always saves the stash with the string "on " prepended to whatever message I passed. Is there a way to tell git not to do that? Right now, I just vim `.git/logs/refs/stash` to manually remove it, but that's not preferable.

Comment: I'm not aware of any option for this off the top of my head. Out of curiosity, why do you want to remove this text? It's meant to be helpful.

Comment: To be honest, it's partly out of curiousity, but also because to me it adds noise. I want to see a list which says "refactoring foobar.java", "failed attempt to remove XYZ", etc and not have to see "on branch ...." since I don't care about that information.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, as of Git 2.0.0, there is no way to tell Git not to prepend "on " to whatever message is passed to git stash [save].

However, [git-stash is implemented as a POSIX shell script](https://code.google.com/p/git-core/source/browse/git-stash.sh). If you stare at this code, you'll eventually find that the "on " string is always prepended to whatever message you passed.

```
    # create the stash
if test -z "$stash_msg"
then
    stash_msg=$(printf 'WIP on %s' "$msg")
else
    stash_msg=$(printf 'On %s: %s' "$branch" "$stash_msg")
fi
```

If this is an itch you want to scratch, clearly you can edit this file (on Ubuntu, for example, default git stores its scripts in /usr/lib/git-core). I think it would make for a useful change, as git-blame shows this code was produced in 2005!